# Course value of CLLocation class -1 all the time. Why?

Tags: iphone, ios, mapkit, core-location

I want to show the car / bike in the direction of which user is moving, for that i have used course property, but its value is all the time -1. Below is the NSLog value of perticular location :

2013-09-09 11:05:09.930 MapApp[143:907] <+23.05910024,+72.53762685> +/- 65.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 09/09/13 11:05:00 AM India Standard Time

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)map viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    static NSString *AnnotationViewID = @"annotationViewID";

    annotationView = (MKAnnotationView *)[map dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:AnnotationViewID];

    if (annotationView == nil)
    {
        annotationView = [[[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:AnnotationViewID] autorelease];
    }
    annotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Bike.png"];


    NSLog(@"%@",currentLocation);


    annotationView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(45);

    return annotationView;
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    if (newLocation.horizontalAccuracy < 0)
        return;
    if  (!newLocation)
        return;


    currentLocation = newLocation;
    previousLocation = oldLocation;
    if(currentLocation != nil)
    {
        if (myAnnotation)
        {
            [self.myMapView removeAnnotation:myAnnotation];
        }
        CLLocationCoordinate2D location = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(currentLocation.coordinate.latitude, currentLocation.coordinate.longitude);
        myAnnotation = [[MyAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinates:location title:@"Current Location" subTitle:nil];
        [self.myMapView addAnnotation:myAnnotation];
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to be *moving* to get a course and speed reading from the GPS.  That is not a compass heading from the magnetometer.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the documentation here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/GettingHeadings/GettingHeadings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH5-SW1

Getting the heading or course of the device is not trivial, but the most likely reason it is -1 that I can think of is you haven't set the app's required device capabilities to include GPS or magnetometer. The device can decide not to calculate either to conserve power. It is worth thinking about whether you actually need this as a strict requirement.

Comment: I have set Required Device Capability flag to magnetometer, but this problem remains unsolved.

Comment: Can you suggest another solution for it, David ?